# CORS issue in Chrome Browser using Unity WEBGL build and chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, single-page-application, unity-webgl

**Introduction :**
I am using Unity WebGL build to play contents on the Bowser, But In browser unity webgl build is taking time to load. So in order to not load the unity webgl library again and again, I have a chrome extension to load the unity webgl build once and play contents on it.

Contents are data driven, so once loaded it gets data [ Audio , video , json ] from s3.

I will play the contents using extension, if it is available. Else I will play content on the browser itself.

**Test Scenario 1 :**

Setup :
Chrome extension is Disabled ( developer mode ).

Steps :
Click on a content, it will play fine.
Now enable the chrome extension ( developer mode )
Try to play the same content, it will try to play in the Chrome extension, it plays fine.

**Test Scenario 2 :**

Setup :
Chrome extension is enabled ( developer mode ).

Steps :

Click on a content, it plays in the extension.
Disable the chrome extension ( developer mode )
Try to play the same content, it will try to play in the browser.

**Error in chrome console :**

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'File url' from origin 'url' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

***My findings :***

*In Test Scenario 2, when I try to play the content in extension , the data required are fetched and stored in the Indexed db of the browser.
When I try to play without extension, the browser is trying to fetch the data from the indexed DB since it is already downloaded and it fails with a CORS issue.
NOTE :
This issue will be solved, if we manually "Empty Cache & hard reload " the browser.*

Image 1 : Loading content  without extension - 1st time
link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QtfMWeHtYjpDy_8jQvmGN2siM5SCEQ4n/view?usp=sharing

Image 2 : Loading the same content again - second time
link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FNzZf_ZPXlCvF19Xhr3yUt3Y9xstMkf-/view?usp=sharing

Image 3 : TestScenario 2
link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vtCpYgsdQwAJ6hgPDCWSO_eajcdNrNHn/view?usp=sharing